# How to run this Java file I found on the Internet? I have already imported ImageJ but I can't seem to let the code run

Tags: image, geometry, imagej

Here's the link to the code: http://rsbweb.nih.gov/ij/plugins/download/Hough_Circles.java

I have already imported ImageJ But I cant seem to let the code run.

Answer (score 2):

Hough_Circles.java is an ImageJ plugin that needs to be run from within ImageJ.

I recommend reading about ImageJ plugins in the [ImageJ User Guide](http://rsbweb.nih.gov/ij/docs/guide/146-16.html#toc-Section-16). From within ImageJ, you can compile and run the plugin by choosing `Plugins > Compile and Run...` from the menu.

If you want to run the code without a GUI, I suggest using the [**Fiji**](http://fiji.sc) distribution of ImageJ, because it allows to run the code in **headless mode** (see [here](http://fiji.sc/Headless)). In Fiji, there's also a very useful [Script Editor](http://fiji.sc/Script_Editor) that allows development of Java plugins as well as scripts in many [scripting languages](http://fiji.sc/Scripting_comparisons).

Comment: Thanks. I really appreciate this. But is there a way I can run the code in a netbeans program or through any java programs?

Comment: @Abby: See this article: http://rsb.info.nih.gov/ij/developer/NBTutorial.html. If you want to run completely "outside" ImageJ, you may need to refactor the code a bit, since `Hough_Circles.java` calls `ImagePlus.show` explicitly.